# GWT 2.5.1 serialization and subclassing issue

Tags: java, gwt, serialization

```
// ChildObjectValue.java
public class ChildObjectValue extends GenericObjectValue {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = xxxx;

    private BigDecimal bigDecimal;

    public BigDecimal getBigDecimal()
    {
        return bigDecimal;
    }

    public void setBigDecimal(BigDecimal bigDecimal)
    {
        this.bigDecimal = bigDecimal;
    }

}

// ChildObjectServiceASync.java
void loadChildObject(AsyncCallback<List<ChildObjectValue>> callback);

// ChildObjectServiceImpl.java
// (...)
List<ChildObjectValue> childrenObjects = new ArrayList<ChildObjectValue>();
ChildObjectValue childObjectValue = new ChildObjectValue();
childObjectValue.setBigDecimal(new BigDecimalChildClass("1.04"));
// BigDecimalChildClass extends BigDecimal but has many dependencies tocomponents not compilable by GWT
// (...)
return childrenObjects; // ASyncCallBack return value
```

Result at execution:
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type '...BigDecimalChildClass' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = 1.04

Indeed, if I change ChildObjectValue.java, and change ChildObjectValue.bigDecimal declaration from BigDecimal to BigDecimalChildClass, GWT will refuse to compile.

I guess the issue comes from the method setBigDecimal(BigDecimal bigDecimal) allowing child classes of BigDecimal as an argument. GWT's DevGuideServerCommunication does say that GWT RPC supports polymorphic parameters and return types, 'though, so I am confused. There must be some limitation I have not quite understood.

I suppose I could change the setBigDecimal method to create a new BigDecimal object from the possibly subclassed argument, but what would be a proper, general solution to this issue ?
Should I have to ensure that for every AsyncCallback type parameter I have, their non-transient fields and set/get parameters are instance of final classes ?

Last but not least, it appears that using BigDecimal does not please GWT. Saving / loading values does work but I end up with that in Eclipse console:
java.lang.InstantiationException: java.math.BigDecimal
Continuing ...
java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to evaluate: =Class.new();
Continuing ...
I suppose it is due to BigDecimal not having a parameterless constructor...what I am to do with that ?

Comment: There are some restrictions in GWT: Have a look here http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html

Comment: "you will save yourself a lot of frustration if you make sure that you use only translatable classes in your client-side code from the very beginning" => yep. What I would like to know about the scenario I am describing is:
- (if possible) To better understand the scenario (what is GWT trying to do ?)
- To prevent the scenario I am describing at compile time (what construct should you recommend ?)